# Cakephp hasManyThrough looking for wrong associated table

Tags: cakephp, model, relationship

I have a hasManyThrough relationship with

```
class Permission extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'PermissionRole'
    );
}

class Role extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'PermissionRole'
    );
}

class PermissionRole extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Permission', 'Role'
    );
}
```

When trying to hit a simple `view` action on the Permission's controller, I'm getting this error:

**"Error: Table permission_roles for model PermissionRole was not found in datasource default"**

According to CakePHP conventions, `permissions_roles` is the correct table name, which is what I have created. Why am I seeing this message, and how do I correct the issue?

Comment: Is there a 'permission_roles' table in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the correct/expected behavior.

The conventions you are referring to only apply to join tables that are used in actual HABTM associations. In that case `permissions_roles` would be correct, which reflects the two models/tables that it connects.

However you are not using an actual HABTM association in the sense of using the HABTM functionality provided by the ORM (`Model::$hasAndBelongsToMany`), but you are manually creating a many-to-many association, using one-to-many and many-to-one associations, and so the default table name conventions apply, where the plural model name is being used, and that is `permission_roles`.

The solution is to simply rename your table.

Comment: With that explanation, it all suddenly makes sense. Thanks!